# Split a binary to groups of 0s and 1s and get the boundary index

Tags: python, regex, split, binary, python-itertools

I have a binary number which I need to group into groups of 0s and 1s.
Also I need to get the starting and ending index of each such newly formed group

For example, suppose the number is `1100111100`

I need to group it as  `11,00,1111,00`

Now the starting and ending index of each group should be like

`11  : (1,2) , 00  : (3,4) , 1111:(5,8)   and 00: (9,10)`

I am planning to use Python. I researched and found itertools can help but not sure which function to use in itertools.

Any help is deeply appreciated

Thanks

Comment: If you are not concerned about efficiency, then the easiest strategy is to convert to string, and keep track of changes '1'->'0'

Comment: A quick and dirty solution: b=binary string 
b_split=b.replace('10', '1 0').replace('01','0 1').split()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with regex like this in one line

```
a = "1100111100"
[' : '.join([i.group(),str((i.start()+1,i.end()))]) for i in re.finditer("0+|1+",a)]
```

re.finditer

> Return an iterator yielding match objects over all non-overlapping matches for the RE pattern in string.

meaning all unique hits are returned in an iterator

Output

```
['11 : (1, 2)', '00 : (3, 4)', '1111 : (5, 8)', '00 : (9, 10)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

str = '1100111100'
l = re.findall('0+|1+', str)    # now l = ['11', '00', '1111', '00']
l2 = []
pos = 1
for x in l:
    l2.append("%s : (%d,%d)" % (x, pos, pos + len(x) - 1))
    pos += len(x)

print(l2)
```

Output:

```
['11 : (1,2)', '00 : (3,4)', '1111 : (5,8)', '00 : (9,10)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using itertools.groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

def func(string):
    i = 1
    for _, g in groupby(string):
        g = ''.join(g)
        j = len(g)
        yield (i, i+j-1), g
        i += j

>>> dict(func('1100111100'))
{(1, 2): '11', (3, 4): '00', (5, 8): '1111', (9, 10): '00'}
```

To use it as a dict, keys must be your ending and starting index and the values are the substrings.